# tf error base_link to map

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new in ROS and I need to continue a project. When i try to launch it, I've got this warning.

```
[ WARN] [1438259230.147675462, 875.589000000]: Waiting on transform from simplebot/base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 875.589 timeout was 0.1.
```

I don't know what does it mean and where to look. I've look on ROS answer but I didn't find anything which help me.

Here is the tf tree.

[image description http://imageshack.com/a/img673/5930/IGiH01.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img673/5930/IGiH01.png)

If anyone can help me :).

Regards
jlimons

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214945/tf-error-base_link-to-map/) by [jlimons](https://answers.ros.org/users/23405/jlimons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-07-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The message is complaining that `canTransform()` is not able to get the relationship of simplebot/base_link to /map. This is because you only have a frame called "base_link" instead of "simplebot/base_link".

So modify your code by changing the arguments of `canTransform()`.

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2015-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1